# RabbitMQ Cluster App

Tags: java, rabbitmq, cluster-computing

it may be a rubbish question, but I googled it whole day and couldn't find anything related. 
I have setup RabbitMQ cluster with 1 stat, 1 disc and 2 RAM node. Now I want to test it. I want to write producer and consumer for this clustered setup. I couldn't find any help on internet. Do you have any pointer or link? I have created an sample application which runs fine on single instance of RAbbitMQ, but I don't know how should i develop application for clustered environment?

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasted from the RabbitMQ clustering guide (https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html):

**A client can connect as normal to any node within a cluster.** If that node should fail, and the rest of the cluster survives, then the client should notice the closed connection, and should be able to reconnect to some surviving member of the cluster. Generally, it's not advisable to bake in node hostnames or IP addresses into client applications: this introduces inflexibility and will require client applications to be edited, recompiled and redeployed should the configuration of the cluster change or the number of nodes in the cluster change. Instead, we recommend a more abstracted approach: this could be a dynamic DNS service which has a very short TTL configuration, or a plain TCP load balancer, or some sort of mobile IP achieved with pacemaker or similar technologies. In general, this aspect of managing the connection to nodes within a cluster is beyond the scope of RabbitMQ itself, and we recommend the use of other technologies designed specifically to solve these problems.

In other words, you can use the test program you already wrote and simply run it against the cluster.